# Invalid Number in multi select- BI Publisher 10.1.3.4

Tags: sql, regex, oracle10g

I am using the below query in BIP and it throws **'Invalid Number'** error. The same query works fine in Toad. Can somebody tell me why I get ***ORA-01722: invalid number*** .When only 1 parameter is used, it works fine, only when we select more than 1 option, we get this error.

We are using **String datatype** for the parameter **ref_std**

Here is the gist of what values each contain

**multilist01 - contains csv values like ',100,200,300,400,'**

**: ref_std - will be a parameter(multi select) like EN 60439-1:1999,EN 60439-3:1991**

---

```
select * from
( 
select cert.multilist01
from
some_table 
) xx
join 
(

select id as input from some_table where item_number in 
(
select regexp_substr(:ref_std,'[^,]+', 1, level) ID
from dual
connect by regexp_substr(:ref_std,'[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
) 


)yy on xx.multilist01 like '%'||yy.input||'%'
```

Comment: I would start by testing the yy query carefully to see if you have values with commas cropping up

Answer (score 0):

First: Item_number must be String because ref_std not is a number, or you have to change '[^,]+' for to extract the number.
if cert.multilist01 is rows with 100 200 300, then this is number, you cannot 'join' with 'yy' that is String.
You have to convert cert.multilist01 in String (Column in some_table) Or you have to extract only the number in ref_std changing the regular expression.

Comment: try to revise your answer :)